# Menu item from closed program stays on top

Tags: windows-7, always-on-top

Sometimes some programs leave a remnant of a menu-item or a button behind on my screen.

It usually shows on top of everything, which makes this pretty annoying.

Closing the program does not remove the menu-item.

Here is an example (the "New Session..." menu-item is from a closed Putty-session):
[image]

What is the easiest way to refresh my screen to remove such a remnant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh yes, we love these remnant GUI elements or artifacts - I've seen them on every OS/GUI I've ever worked with.

Starting a screensaver is a very quick way to clear these as you can trigger it with a keystroke [1].  Another quick trick is changing screen resolutions - which you can quickly do on a laptop with the built-in mirror screen function button.

Eventually you learn the best practice is to clear these elements when they come up - by not allowing them to stick around in the first place or re-triggering the very same element as soon as it sticks.

-Z

[1] Create a screensaver hot-key
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-screen-saver-boss-key-in-windows-7.html

Comment: I like the mirror screen solution!

Comment: Changing screen resolution works for me, but a screensaver doesn't help on W7. Thanks!

Comment: For Windows 7 you can kill 'dwm.exe' in task manager. You can do this without harm, and the artifacts will be gone

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question, it's still a relevant issue today on my Windows 7 machine.
There are two workarounds which work for me; hopefully they'll help someone else with the same issue.

#### Restart the DWM service

You should be able to clear artifacts by restarting the Desktop Window Manager.  You can make this easy to do with a simple desktop shortcut, which you can also assign a hotkey to:

1. Create a new shortcut on the desktop with the following command-line:
   `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "net stop UxSms & sc start UxSms"`
2. Edit the properties of the new shortcut and assign a hotkey; I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-d
3. Also in the shortcut's properties select `Advanced` and ensure `Run as administrator` is checked

This should look similar to:
[image]

#### Change the Windows Performance setting

1. Open the Windows performance options dialog by either of:

   1. Type `Adjust performance` into the Start menu search, and select `Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows`
   2. `Control Panel` | `Performance Information and Tools` | `Adjust visual effects`
2. Turn off the checkbox for `Fade out menu items after clicking`:
   [image]