# Menus sticks on top of everything

Tags: windows-7

I have the same problem as this:

[Menu item from closed program stays on top](https://superuser.com/questions/270470/menu-item-from-closed-program-stays-on-top)

I can refresh the resolution, and then the problem disappears, but then after the problem comes back, it is 10 times worse. Almost every time I do something the sticky menu will appear more often. The only solution so far is to restart the computer.

Do anybody know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to a broken program you have installed. Figure out which is the offender and see if there is an update.

Also check for graphics drivers updates, for both integrated (intel GPU) and discreet (if any - NVIDIA or AMD).

Comment: Ok hmm that is hard to figureout any way to do it, or do I have to reinstall windows, I got nvidia.

Comment: How do I find the program that is broken. Maby a reinstall of windows is easier. Can it be a plugin in chrome, becuse it does the same on my working computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Go to **Start Menu**, and right click **Computer**, then click **Properties**.
2. On the left pane, click **Advanced System Settings**.
3. Click the **Advanced** tab, then click the **Settings** button under the **Performance** section.
4. *Uncheck* the following:

   - Fade or slide menus into view
   - Fade or slide Tooltips into view
   - Fade out menu items after clicking
5. Click Apply, then OK.

   [image]

As to why this occurs in Windows, no one really knows much more than it just being a bug, probably driver-related. The screen refresh trick and this are the only known solutions.

Comment: Ok I will try this and then report back to see if it helps.